# Loading multiple scripts with jsdom.jQueryify

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to load an additional .js script using:

```
["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js","http://someotrherscript.js"]
```

In `jsdom.jQueryify`

```
jsdom.jQueryify(window, 
    ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js","http://someotrherscript.js"], function () {
          window.$("body").append('<div class="testing">Hello World, It works</div>');
          console.log(window.$(".testing").text());
        });
```

It's not working, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

```
var scriptEl = window.document.createElement("script");
      scriptEl.src = "/Library/WebServer/Documents/www/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.js";
        window.$("body").append(scriptEl);
```